# Launching another iPhone App from my App and if it is already installed or not?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios, custom-url

Launching another iPhone App from my App? This feature needs to behave like this:-

a) If the App is not installed, then open the App Store with the application selected

b) If the App is installed, then open the Application

I already have custom URL. So I am able to open given app if it is installed on iPhone. **But I want to to send user to app store if it is not installed already, so that he can download the app and start using it right away**

***How to check if app is already installed or not?? Please help.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `canOpenURL:` on `UIApplication` to see if there is an app which can respond to your custom URL. If this returns true, use the custom URL to open the app, otherwise open a link to the App Store

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512228/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-app-is-installed). This should be the code you need to achieve what you are trying to:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR-URL-SCHEME://"]]) {
// Your App is installed
} else {
// Open iTunes
}
```