# check whether a particular app is running or not iOS?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to detect whether a particular app is running or not from my application.

I have an `API call` which will fire `every 5 min` interval in app background, before making call I wants to detect whether a  particular app is running or not. If app is running then will make `API call` else will look next time.

Comment: No. and you can't schedule your app to run every 5 minutes either

Comment: check my answer. @Anupam Mishra

Comment: check this link, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-‌​which-apps-are-backg‌​round-and-which-app-‌​is-foreground-on-ios‌​-by/12315750#1231575‌​0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bwhich-apps-are-backg%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bround-and-which-app-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bis-foreground-on-ios%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-by/12315750#1231575%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0) Hope this will helpful to you. But it's not good to call api at every 5 mins.

Comment: I mistakenly marked this as a duplicate when the question I was marking was too old. This is now not possible by any of the solutions given in the linked answers. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in iOS without jailbreaking.

Nonetheless, there is a workaround but for limited apps. check these answers: 
[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512228/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-app-is-installed)], 
[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone)], 
[[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios)]
Also [this](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) will help you.

And please search a bit before posting similar question.