# how to access a sound file stored in another app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, sandbox

this question is a lot like [Share data between two or more iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications) except:

- I'm looking for a way to do this in an iOS 8+ (or 9+) application using *swift*
- I want to be able to use the sound file contained in the first app so the easter egg I'm making is only available when the user has both apps installed
- since this is part of an easter egg, i don't want to use any method that would cause anything extra to be displayed on screen such as a browser redirect or some kind of permission popup

(this basically rules out using the share sheet and custom url's to pass data as described in the post above)

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` and `AVAudioSession` in the first app to play the sound if that is at all helpful.

Comment: Can't you use an URLscheme to check if both apps are installed and bundle/stream the sound to both apps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512228/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-app-is-installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use App Group

You can share actual `NSData` through the `NSUserDefaults`:

```
if let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: <group>) {
    userDefaults.setObject(obj, forKey: key)
}
```

and retrieve from another app in the same group like so:

```
if let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: <group>) {
    if let obj = userDefaults.objectForKey(key)  {
        // magic
    }
}
```

---

It appears that the only limitation for passing data through the user defaults is the device storage capacity, and since `NSUserDefaults` accepts `NSData` as a storage format, it makes a prime candidate for sharing tidbits information.

Comment: Nice. Let's remove some of the comments, including this one!

Answer (score 0):

If both apps are yours you can implement a custom url scheme in the second app, and then from the first app ask if it knows how to open an URL with that scheme. If the answer is yes, the app is installed. The function is called `canOpenURL`. It's an instance method of `UIApplication`.

I vaguely remember that in iOS 9 and later, Apple added a restriction that you have to register the URLs you are going to ask about in your info.plist, but I don't remember the details. That won't prevent this scheme from working, but it is an extra step you have to take.

Comment: how about passing the audio data or accessing it from the second app without changing the on-screen display for the user?