# Is it possible to see what other apps are on an unjailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Any way to do this: I would like to see what other apps are installed on a user's iPhone. I would think not but I'm positive that somebody would know better than me.

If not, can you access on desktop via iTunes?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "observe"?  what are you trying to do?

Comment: See which other apps are installed - agreed poor choice of words

Comment: The other apps installed on a user's phone shouldn't be your concern. What are you intending to do with the information if you get it? If you're not really careful, you can cause yourself serious problems here (the least of which is user complaints about your app invading their privacy).

Comment: This question has been asked before: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243567/how-to-check-installed-application-in-iphone-device)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check the file system for other apps since you can't see anything outside of your sandbox (except iCloud, photos, etc). However, as mentioned in other answers, you can check to see if an app's URL scheme is available.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {

    //Facebook is installed

}
```

This is useful if you want to open something, such as a new post for the user in Facebook. If you do not intend on using this feature for the direct benefit of the user, **then don't use it**. It's a complete violation of their privacy.