# Can you find out what apps the user has installed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to determine if a user has a specific app installed, or even to count how many apps they have installed?

The information would be used to target information passed to the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check installed application in iphone device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243567/how-to-check-installed-application-in-iphone-device)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not on a stock phone. Jailbroken maybe, but I have not played with the jailbroken side of things.

You could try to open an app via a [URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899). Using Twitter as an example, one of its URL schemes is `twitter://user?screen_name=somename`

You can check if you can open that URL:

```
NSURL *tURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=somename"];
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:tURL] )
   // if here, you can open twitter app
```

You can extrapolate from here if you want.

Comment: Yup, pretty much what i thought.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the apps in question are known to you as a developer of that feature and do implement custom URL schemas (which you also need to know). There is a service that tries to collect that information: [handleopenurl.com](http://handleopenurl.com)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: there are ways to detect if certain apps that provide the capability are present.  For example, the Facebook app ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512228/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-app-is-installed)).  However, it is not possible to detect apps that do not support that kind of detection, and it is not possible to get a total count of apps (unless, of course, they only had detectable apps, but the likelihood of that is incredibly slim).

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No. On iOS, there are a few methods which can be used, but they won't get you the entire list, only some of the apps. Daniel Amitay has a nice framework for this. You can find it [here (iHasApp)](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp/)

I have used it and it gets most of the apps, but as I said, not all. Daniel explains in his [blog post](http://danielamitay.com/blog/2011/2/16/how-to-detect-installed-ios-apps) what techniques you can use.